# Validate string not having @ symbol for textarea

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation.
Currently, I have a text field. How can I prompt an alert when user types an `@` (at) character in the field?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkAtSymbol", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || /[^@]$/.test(value);
},"Please check your input.");
```

Comment: @stribizhev, tried. Not working!!. /[^@]$/ works but when you hit space, validation fails.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to suggest `/^[^@]*$/`.

Comment: @stribizhev. Perfect. Thanks alot !!!

Comment: Posted as a solution, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
/^[^@]*$/
```

This pattern checks if the complete input string (from beginning to end) consists of characters other than `@`, or is empty.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT3eB9/2)